# Use private nested class in a public interface of an enclosing class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have faced an interesting dilemma during implementing a custom data structure. Unfortunately I could not found any answer in the C++11 standard, so I hope someone can explain it to me.

There is a class which has a private nested class. Also it uses this private sub-class as a return value in a public function. Like this:

```
class Enclosing {
private:
    // Private nested class
    struct Nested {
        Nested(int x) : _x(x) {}
        int _x;
    };

    Nested _nested;

public:
    Enclosing():_nested(42) {}

    // Use private nested class in public interface
    const Nested& get_nested() {
        return _nested;
    }
};
```

If I try to use call `get_nested` it compiles, although I can not create a local variable of type `Enclosing::Nested` to store the result. But this is where `auto` comes to rescue:

```
int main() {
    Enclosing e;
    //Enclosing::Nested n = e.get_ref( ); //Error! Enclosing::Nested is private
    auto n = e.get_nested( );             //Ok, unless we name a type
    cout << n._x << endl;
}
```

Even more, with some variadic templates magic I can even call a constructor of the nested class and screate a new exemplar of it:

```
template<class T, typename... Args>
T* create(const T& t, Args... args) {
    return new T(args...);
}

int main() {
    Enclosing e;
    // We can even create a new instance of the private nested class
    auto np = create(e.get_nested( ), 68); 
    //Enclosing::Nested* np = create(e.get_nested( ), 68); // But don't name a type
    cout << np->_x << endl;
}
```

Could please anybody explain this behavior to me? Why does `auto` permit us access to the otherwise private data type? There must be some obvious reason which I just can not see so far. Reference to the paragraph in the Standard is highly welcome.

Thank you very much!

(checked in gcc 4.7.3 and clang 3.2)

Comment: Don't make it private then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the duplicate, which explains it, you can actually *improve* the intention of the author of the private class by making the members of the inner class private and declaring the outer class as a `friend`. That way your seconds example (`create`) won't compile anymore (in practice, add an explicit and hence private copy-ctor as well):

```
class Nested {
    Nested(int x) : _x(x) {}
    int _x;
    friend class Enclosing;
};
```

This ensures that all instances of `Nested` are created from `Enclosing`.